# I have problem in changing the color in the console, I have imported nmp modules chalk but it is showing ESM require error. I don't understand

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, node-modules, chalk

How to resolve the **ESM** *require* problem, I have tried a lot to resolve it but I was unable to fix this out.

Comment: A few sentences are usually not enough to show others what you experienced. If you cannot easily describe the details, attach some screen shots. BTW, I removed the monodevelop tag as it does not seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk#install

> IMPORTANT: Chalk 5 is ESM. If you want to use Chalk with TypeScript or a build tool, you will probably want to use Chalk 4 for now. Read more.

For chalk 5 and above you'll need *import* statement:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

Otherwise, use chalk 4 with *require* statement:

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
```